# Hibernate : Generic JDBC exception - Bad format for Time '838:59:59'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have hibernate mapping as follow:

```
<property formula="(Timediff(ifnull(sttime,now()),sstime))" insert="false" name="duration" update="false" />
where sstime is of type Timestamp
```

here this formula returns some value in this format "838:59:59" from my data.

I got the exception when i am trying to load this value in 'Duration' field, which has 'java.sql.Time' type, it gives me this exception.

```
"Generic JDBC exception - Bad format for Time '838:59:59'"
```

Comment: Similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733148/surpassing-mysqls-time-value-limit-of-8385959

Answer (score 3):

That's indeed not a valid time. You should not use a java.sql.Time to represent a duration, especially if this duration is potential longer tha 24 hours, since a Time represents the time portion of a date. Use a custom type instead, or simply a string that you'll parse yourself.

Comment: ok...so is there any way so that i can change the behavior of hibernate and manually parse it to Time format.?
and thank you for replying...

Comment: Declare your field as a String instead of declaring it as a Time.

Answer (score 1):

From the source

http://www.microshell.com/database/mysql/getting-around-mysql-timediff-maximum-value-of-8385959/

Use TIMESTAMPDIFF instead of TIMEDIFF in formulae

Comment: but it has the DateTime in its parameter and i have TimeStamp for it. TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)

Answer (score 1):

Following the MySQL documentation you should use TIMESTAMPDIFF() and UNIX_TIMESTAMP():

> The result returned by TIMEDIFF() is limited to the range allowed for
>   TIME values. Alternatively, you can use either of the functions
>   TIMESTAMPDIFF() and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), both of which return integers.

Query may look something like this, but is dependent from the result data type that you are using:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,sstime,NOW())) FROM time_table;

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(sstime)) FROM time_table;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed5872/17)

Comment: I think may works for me...
To try this i need to write following line:<property formula="(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,ifnull(sttime,now()),sstime))" insert="false" name="duration" update="false" /> and hibernate make 'SECOND' as 'this_.SECOND'.so how can i solve this problem..?