# SUM time values MySQL

Tags: mysql, time, mysql-workbench

I am trying to sum time values and have it in the format of hours:minutes:seconds i.e. 100:30:10.

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ActualHours))) AS Hours
```

But I'm having a problem because time's max value is 838:59:59.
So if summing the time is over this value it won't show i.e. if it equals 900 hours it will show as 838:59:59 which is wrong.

How do I the display the total hours if it is over 838:59:59?

Comment: I think you need not convert it back using `SEC_TO_TIME` and let it be in seconds. In your application code you can do the conversion.

Comment: use a series of `MOD` and `DIV` operations, to extract seconds (remainder dividing by 60), minutes   (subtract seconds, divide by 60, then remainder of another divide by 60, to get minutes, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way we can do this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(CAST(FLOOR(seconds / 3600) AS CHAR(50)), ':',
           CAST(FLOOR(60*((seconds / 3600) - FLOOR(seconds / 3600))) AS CHAR(50)), ':',
           CAST(seconds % 60 AS CHAR(50))) AS time
FROM yourTable;
```

For an input of 10,000,000 (ten million) seconds, this would generate:

```
2777:46:40
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks this worked

Comment: Note that this won't add a leading zero for single digit minutes or seconds.  For a seconds value of 3999960, this expression will return `1111:6:0`

Comment: @spencer7593 Yes, but since the hours component is no longer limited to a max width of two digits, this requirement did not seem so important.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to do this conversion in SQL, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(              (   _secs_    DIV 3600)
         , ':'
         , RIGHT(CONCAT('0',(   _secs_    DIV 60  ) MOD 60 ),2)
         , ':'
         , RIGHT(CONCAT('0',(   _secs_              MOD 60)),2)
       ) AS `h:mm:ss`
```

We can just replace the `_secs_` with the expression that returns the number of seconds we want to convert. Using the expression given in the question, we get something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(              (  SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ActualHours))  DIV 3600)
         , ':'
         , RIGHT(CONCAT('0',(  SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ActualHours))  DIV 60  ) MOD 60 ),2)
         , ':'
         , RIGHT(CONCAT('0',(  SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ActualHours))            MOD 60)),2)
       ) AS `h:mm:ss`
```

---

**DEMONSTRATION**

The syntax provided in this answer is valid in MySQL 5.6. As a demonstration, using a user-defined variable `@_secs` as the expression number of seconds:

Set user-defined variable for demonstration:

```
SELECT @_secs_ := ( 987 * 3600 ) + ( 5 * 60 ) + 7  ;
```

returns

```
@_secs := ( 987 * 3600 ) + ( 5 * 60 ) + 7  
-----------------------------------------
                                  3553507
```

demonstrating the query pattern:

```
SELECT CONCAT(              (  @_secs_    DIV 3600) 
         , ':'
         , RIGHT(CONCAT('0',(  @_secs_    DIV 60  ) MOD 60 ),2)
         , ':'
         , RIGHT(CONCAT('0',(  @_secs_              MOD 60)),2)
       ) AS `hhh:mm:ss`
```

returns

```
  hhh:mm:ss
  ---------
  987:05:07
```

Comment: I get the an error with this query: error Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: I believe the syntax provided in this question is valid. The expression after the SELECT keyword should be valid a replacement for the expression shown in the question, obviously with the placeholder `_secs_` replaced with an expression that is valid in the context of the query.

Comment: Instead of 'RIGHT(CONCAT())' it might be cleaner to use LPAD as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294152/2988142
Also CONCAT_WS(':', ...) looks a bit better in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use some simple math to concat a time period from seconds,replace 35000 with your column.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(35000/3600),':',FLOOR((35000%3600)/60),':',(35000%3600)%60)
```

A [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/63297) to play with

Comment: I get the an error with this query: error Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax;