# How to store Derived Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a **table A** which have **Start_time** and **End_time** as columns, i am calculating the difference of these two columns as

```
Select timediff(End_time, Start_time) as TF from A
```

Now i want to sum of all time periods present ln **TF** column.

I searched alot but could not found anything related to it

Comment: You should include what was the issue, what you have tried,a sample data and corresponding output.

Comment: @JitendraYadav It is mentioned that PS want to get SUM of time periods vin HH:MM:SS format in comments

Answer (score 1):

`Timediff()` will give you result in `HH:MM:SS` format. In order to `SUM()` them up, you need to first convert them into numbers (in this case, seconds); add them up using `SUM()`; and then convert them back to `HH:MM:SS` format:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF(End_time, Start_time) ) ) ) 
FROM A
```

Comment: upvoted for correcting other's answer before posting yours

Comment: I think you need to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733148/surpassing-mysqls-time-value-limit-of-8385959